Permission denied error when executing file or plugin
I'm trying to create a packer build as follows, and am getting permission denied.  As I'm also seeing the same problem when trying to execute a shell script, I think the root cause may be an OS layer misconfiguration (see below).  The issue here is that with a shell script, I have a workaround of running "bash scriptname.sh" whereas I don't have that option here with packer.
PACKER_LOG=1 packer init .
+ PACKER_LOG=1
+ packer init .
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [INFO] Packer version: 1.10.3 [go1.20.12 linux amd64]
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [TRACE] discovering plugins in /usr/bin
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [TRACE] discovering plugins in .
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [TRACE] discovering plugins in /home/userid/.config/packer/plugins
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [INFO] PACKER_CONFIG env var not set; checking the default config file path
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [INFO] PACKER_CONFIG env var set; attempting to open config file: /home/userid/.packerconfig
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [WARN] Config file doesn't exist: /home/userid/.packerconfig
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [INFO] Setting cache directory: /home/userid/.cache/packer
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [TRACE] init: plugingetter.ListInstallationsOptions{FromFolders:[]string{"/usr/bin", ".", "/home/userid/.config/packer/plugins"}, BinaryInstallationOptions:plugingetter.BinaryInstallationOptions{APIVersionMajor:"5", APIVersionMinor:"0", OS:"linux", ARCH:"amd64", Ext:"", Checksummers:[]plugingetter.Checksummer{plugingetter.Checksummer{Type:"sha256", Hash:(*sha256.digest)(0xc00035d400)}}}}
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [TRACE] listing potential installations for "github.com/hashicorp/vsphere" that match "~> 1". plugingetter.ListInstallationsOptions{FromFolders:[]string{"/usr/bin", ".", "/home/userid/.config/packer/plugins"}, BinaryInstallationOptions:plugingetter.BinaryInstallationOptions{APIVersionMajor:"5", APIVersionMinor:"0", OS:"linux", ARCH:"amd64", Ext:"", Checksummers:[]plugingetter.Checksummer{plugingetter.Checksummer{Type:"sha256", Hash:(*sha256.digest)(0xc00035d400)}}}}
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [TRACE] getting available versions for the github.com/hashicorp/vsphere plugin
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [WARNING] github-getter: no GitHub token set, if you intend to install plugins often, please set the PACKER_GITHUB_API_TOKEN env var
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [DEBUG] github-getter: getting "https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/packer-plugin-vsphere/git/matching-refs/tags"
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [DEBUG] will try to install: [1.2.7 1.2.6 1.2.5 1.2.4 1.2.3 1.2.2 1.2.1 1.2.0 1.1.2 1.1.1 1.1.0 1.0.8 1.0.7 1.0.6 1.0.5 1.0.4 1.0.3 1.0.2 1.0.1 1.0.0]
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] fetching checksums file for the "1.2.7" version of the github.com/hashicorp/vsphere plugin in "/home/userid/.config/packer/plugins/github.com/hashicorp/vsphere"...
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [DEBUG] github-getter: getting "https://github.com/hashicorp/packer-plugin-vsphere/releases/download/v1.2.7/packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_SHA256SUMS"
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] ignoring invalid remote binary packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_darwin_amd64.zip: wrong system, expected linux_amd64
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] ignoring invalid remote binary packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_darwin_arm64.zip: wrong system, expected linux_amd64
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] ignoring invalid remote binary packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_freebsd_386.zip: wrong system, expected linux_amd64
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] ignoring invalid remote binary packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_freebsd_amd64.zip: wrong system, expected linux_amd64
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] ignoring invalid remote binary packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_freebsd_arm.zip: wrong system, expected linux_amd64
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] ignoring invalid remote binary packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_386.zip: wrong system, expected linux_amd64
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] About to get: packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64.zip
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [DEBUG] github-getter: getting "https://github.com/hashicorp/packer-plugin-vsphere/releases/download/v1.2.7/packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64.zip"
Installed plugin github.com/hashicorp/vsphere v1.2.7 in "/home/userid/.config/packer/plugins/github.com/hashicorp/vsphere/packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64"
2024/05/06 11:35:05 [INFO] (telemetry) Finalizing.
2024/05/06 11:35:06 waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
++ date +%Y%m%dt%H%M%S
+ packer build -var vm_name=name-here -var-file=pkrvars/pkrvars.hcl .
 Error loading configuration:

fork/exec /home/userid/.config/packer/plugins/github.com/hashicorp/vsphere/packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64: permission denied

Yet, the directory permissions look fine to me:
[userid@host  vsphere]$ ls -la  /home/userid/.config/packer/plugins
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 3 userid userid 24 May  6 11:35 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 userid userid 73 May  6 11:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 3 userid userid 23 May  6 11:35 github.com

[userid@host  vsphere]$ ls -la  /home/userid/.config/packer/plugins/github.com/hashicorp/vsphere/
total 61096
drwxr-xr-x. 2 userid userid      122 May  6 11:35 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 userid userid       21 May  6 11:35 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 userid userid 62558208 May  6 11:35 packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid userid       64 May  6 11:35 packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64_SHA256SUM


[userid@host  vsphere]$ file packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64
packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped

I get the same error if I replace the build statement with:
PACKER_LOG=1 packer plugins install github.com/hashicorp/vsphere

That said, I have a feeling it has something to do with the following, i.e. that I can't run ./executable.
[userid@host  vsphere]$ vi test.sh
[userid@host  vsphere]$ chmod 0755 test.sh
[userid@host  vsphere]$ ./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied

[userid@host  vsphere]$ bash test.sh
This is a test

[userid@host vsphere]$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is a test"

In the same way, executing the plugin executable doesn't work, either:
[userid@host vsphere]$ . ./packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64
-bash: .: ./packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64: cannot execute binary file
[user@host vsphere]$ ./packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64
-bash: ./packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64: Permission denied
[user@host vsphere]$ export PATH=${PATH}:.
[user@host vsphere]$ packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64
-bash: ./packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64: Permission denied

I don't think it's SELinux related, as the output below looks fine to me.
[user@host vsphere]$ ls -latZ .
total 61104
drwxr-xr-x. 2 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0     4096 May  6 15:17 .
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0       35 May  6 15:17 test.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0        0 May  6 14:56 plugins.hwm
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0        0 May  6 14:56 plugins.pwd
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0        0 May  6 14:56 plugins.pwi
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0       64 May  6 11:35 packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64_SHA256SUM
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0 62558208 May  6 11:35 packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64
drwxr-xr-x. 3 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0       21 May  6 11:35 ..

I further confirmed that this is not SELinux related by running setenforce=0 and re-running what I did above.
Any thoughts as to how I can get the packer plugin working?

the ./ changes things a little. I am by no means well-versed, but see, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-executable-or-script-name-to-run-it-in-bas

@Yorik thanks.  Yes, I realize it's different.  Per the article you mentioned, if the current directory . is in the PATH, I should be able to execute the file, but per what I posted above, I'm getting permission denied.  Moreover, the original error includes the full pathname of the executable file from the plugin, so that doesn't quite explain it... maybe it's in fact not an OS issue but a packer issue?
